# The text for this answer does not fit the box

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image: the bug]

A link to the answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/275675/6134

My guess is that those formulas don't get their height calculated correctly.

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5345a)

Comment: But now I don't have the issue anymore when I visit that answer. Maybe the question got edited while I was looking at the question?